# DateTimePicker getting the month value jQuery

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using the [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

What I am looking for is to alert the month value when the value for this changes.

I know that `Date` objects in jQuery contain a method called `getMonth()` but this does not work for this scenario.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        var newDate = $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date();
        alert(newDate);
    });
});
```

If I tried to do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        var newDate = $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date();
        var month = newDate.getMonth();
        alert(month);
    });
});
```

This will produce an error saying that `newDate` doesn't contain a method for `getMonth()`, which I understand.. so is there another way to retrieve the month value?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using moment.js with it?

Comment: @charlietfl yes I am

Comment: Well , docs say it returns a moment object...so use moment methods to get what you need. See moment.js docs

Comment: @charlietfl ahh that did it.  I must've read right over that.  Can you show me where you saw that, please?

Comment: I have never used this plugin so i went to docs link ...looked at date function and it tells you what is returned from it... *"Returns the component's model current date, a moment object or null if not set."*

Comment: If you had simply logged it to console you would also see it is a moment object

Comment: @charlietfl ahh thank you. if you want to post a solution that includes the advice you gave about moment.js documentation I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using moment.js in page the `date()` method returns a moment object and you need to use moment api methods on that object, not native Date methods